# UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK query not creating the expected lock

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I have the below table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm learning how SQL locks work, and I'm trying to test a situation where I want to lock a row from being read and updated. Some of the inspiration in this quest starting from this [article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx), and here's the [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661462/how-to-lock-a-specific-row-that-doesnt-exist-yet-in-sql-server) I was trying to solve.

When I run this T-SQL:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I would expect an exclusive lock to be placed on the table, and specifically for the row (if I had a WHERE statement on the primary key)

But running this query, I can see that the GRANTed LOCK is for the request mode IX.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID() AND resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table1');
```

Also, in seperate SSMS windows, I can fully query the table while the transaction is running.

Why is MSSQL not respecting the lock hints?

(SQL Server 2016)

**Edit 1**
Any information about how these locks work is appreciated, however, the issue at hand is that SQL Server does not seem to be enforcing the locks I'm specifying. My hunch is that this has to do with row versioning, or something related.

**Edit 2**
I created this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/salzersoftware/96a5bc2534fd55131584af9c55cf64e7). It requires .NET and the external library Dapper to run (available via Nuget package).

Here's the interesting thing I noticed:

- SELECT statements can be ran against `table1` even though a previous query with `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` has been requested.
- INSERT statements cannot be ran while the lock is there
- UPDATE statements against *existing* records cannot be ran while the lock is there
- UPDATE statements against non-existing records *can* be ran.

Here's the Console output of that Gist:

> Run locking SELECT Start - 00:00:00.0165118
>   Run NON-locking SELECT Start - 00:00:02.0155787
>   Run NON-locking SELECT Finished - 00:00:02.0222536
>   Run INSERT Start - 00:00:04.0156334
>   Run UPDATE ALL Start - 00:00:06.0259382
>   Run UPDATE EXISTING Start - 00:00:08.0216868
>   Run UPDATE NON-EXISTING Start - 00:00:10.0236223
>   Run UPDATE NON-EXISTING Finished - 00:00:10.0268826
>   Run locking SELECT Finished - 00:00:31.3204120
>   Run INSERT Finished - 00:00:31.3209670
>   Run UPDATE ALL Finished - 00:00:31.3213625
>   Run UPDATE EXISTING Finished - 00:00:31.3219371

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524155/what-effect-does-holdlock-have-on-updlock#1524803

Comment: `UPDLOCK` isn't expected to block `SELECT` queries. When taken out by update queries this is just an intermediate lock that may be converted to an X lock later.  Why are you expecting an exclusive lock?

Comment: And `resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table1');` will only show you object level locks. This is not the correct query to be using.

Comment: `SELECT dm_tran_locks.* FROM sys.dm_tran_locks LEFT JOIN sys.partitions ON partitions.hobt_id = dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id  WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID() AND CASE WHEN resource_type = 'OBJECT' THEN dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id ELSE partitions.OBJECT_ID END = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table1')`

Comment: Please see the documentation and explain on what basis you are expecting an X lock. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

Comment: @contactmatt What you describe in Edit2 is exactly what expect should happen. Please read the link in my answer below, where Remus explains this.

Comment: I have 2 observations  -  1) if you add update statement instead of select it will not allow to read the data from another windows.  2) if you remove index on the table then lock will be converted to 'X' and you will not be able to read the data from another SSMS window.

Answer (score 5):

> and I'm trying to test a situation where I want to lock a row from
>   being read and updated

If you want to lock a row from being read and updated you need an exclusive lock, but `UPDLOCK` lock hint requests update locks, not exclusive locks. The query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WITH (XLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE Id = <some id>
```

Additionally, under `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` and `SNAPSHOT` isolation levels, `SELECT` statements don't request shared locks, just schema stability locks. Therefore, the `SELECT` statement can read the row despite there is an exclusive lock. And surprisingly, under READ COMMITTED isolation level, SELECT statements might not request row level shared locks. You will need to add a query hint to the `SELECT` statement to prevent it from read the locked row:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 WITH (REPEATABLEREAD)
WHERE id = <some id>
```

With `REPEATABLEREAD` lock hint, the `SELECT` statement will request shared locks and will hold them during the transaction, so it won't read exclusively locked rows. Note that using `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` is not enough, since SQL Server might not request shared locks under some circumstances as described in [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/11/01/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.aspx) blog post.

Please, take a look at the [Lock Compatibility Table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx)

Under the default isolation level `READ COMMITTED`, and with not lock hints, `SELECT` statements request shared locks for each row it reads, and those locks are released immediately after the row is read. However, if you use `WITH (HOLDLOCK)`, the shared locks are held until the transaction ends. Taking into account the lock compatibility table, a `SELECT` statement running under `READ COMMITTED`, can read any row that is not locked exclusively (IX, SIX, X locks). Exclusive locks are requested by `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements or by `SELECT` statements with `XLOCK` hints.

> I would expect an exclusive lock to be placed on the table, and
>   specifically for the row (if I had a WHERE statement on the primary
>   key)
>
> I need to understand WHY SQL Server is not respcting the locking
>   directives given to it. (i.e. Why is an exclusive lock not on the
>   table, or row for that matter?)

`UPDLOCK` hint doesn't request exclusive locks, it requests update locks. Additionally, the lock can be granted on other resources than the row itself, it can be granted on the table, data pages, index pages, and index keys. The complete list of resource types SQL Server can lock is: `DATABASE, FILE, OBJECT, PAGE, KEY, EXTENT, RID, APPLICATION, METADATA, HOBT, and ALLOCATION_UNIT`. When `ROWLOCK` hint is specified, SQL Server will lock rows, not pages nor extents nor tables and the actual resources that SQL Server will lock are `RID`'s and `KEY`'s

Comment: As I put in a comment in another answer this won't necessarily do what they want. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/11/01/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith, very interesting. I'll check that

Comment: @MartinSmith. I didn't know that under READ COMMITTED snapshot SELECT statements might not request shared locks. I edited my answer suggesting using REPEATABLEREAD.

Answer (score 1):

@Remus Rusuanu has explained it a lot better than I ever could [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843733/confused-about-updlock-holdlock.).

In essence - you can always read **UNLESS** you ask for the same lock type (or more restrictive). However, if you want to `UPDATE` or `DELETE` then you will be blocked. But as I said, the link above explains it really well.

Comment: I think I understand generally how the lock hints work - my issue is that SQL Server does not seem to be respecting the lock hints at all.

Comment: @contactmatt When you say SQL Server does not respect the hint at all, what do you mean?

Comment: When I query for existing locks, only the IX lock appears - no exclusive locks appear on the table. I can also open up other connections and freely query/modify the table's data in the middle of the transaction.

Comment: Please provide a full repro where you can **modify** the table's data whilst the other tran is open.

Comment: @MartinSmith please see the update on my question. Also, shouldn't the UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK prevent READs and not just modifications?

Comment: No. It shouldn't prevent reads. And your update shows that you didn't successfully modify any data. An update against a non existing row doesn't modify anything.

Comment: See lock compatibility matrix here. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx S and U locks don't conflict.

Comment: @MartinSmith looks like you're right - do you know how I can prevent reads against a table, or at least again a specific PK?

Comment: Look at XLOCK or TABLOCKX. Though XLOCK doesn't always prevent reads at read committed http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/11/01/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.aspx so that would leave TABLOCKX. Not sure if that will prevent reads under SI or not.

Comment: Do you really need to block *all* reads or just some reads? If you can ensure that the reading queries you care about all have `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` and ideally `ROWLOCK` then what you have is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

> Lock hints ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, AND XLOCK that acquire row-level locks may place locks on index keys rather than the actual data rows. For example, if a table has a nonclustered index, and a SELECT statement using a lock hint is handled by a covering index, a lock is acquired on the index key in the covering index rather than on the data row in the base table.

This is why you are getting an index lock (IX) and not a table row lock.

And this explains why you can read while running the first query:

http://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/04/14/locking-in-microsoft-sql-server-part-1-lock-types/

> Update locks (U). Those locks are the mix between shared and exclusive locks. SQL Server uses them with data modification statements while searching for the rows need to be modified. For example, if you issue the statement like: “update MyTable set Column1 = 0 where Column1 is null” SQL Server acquires update lock for every row it processes while searching for Column1 is null. When eligible row found, SQL Server converts (U) lock to (X).

Your UPDLock is an update lock.  Notice that update locks are SHARED while searching, and changed EXCLUSIVE when performing the actual update.  Since your query is a select with an update lock hint, the lock is a SHARED lock.  This will allow other queries to also read the rows.